# How do I tell this minecraft fabric mod to use modmenu-2.0.14?

Tags: minecraft-fabric

I want to update this mod (https://github.com/LambdAurora/MCPatcherPatcher) to minecraft version 1.17.1, and I have learned much already. If you had asked me a week ago what gradle was or how github works, I would have given you a blank stare. I have come to a point where I'm stuck in updating this mod:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':fabric'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':fabric:modImplementation'.
   > Could not find com.terraformersmc:modmenu:2.0.14.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - file:/C:/Users/thijm/.m2/repository/com/terraformersmc/modmenu/2.0.14/modmenu-2.0.14.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/terraformersmc/modmenu/2.0.14/modmenu-2.0.14.pom
       - https://aperlambda.github.io/maven/com/terraformersmc/modmenu/2.0.14/modmenu-2.0.14.pom
       - file:/C:/Users/thijm/Desktop/test 1171/nieuw3/MCPatcherPatcher-main/.gradle/loom-cache/remapped_mods/com/terraformersmc/modmenu/2.0.14/modmenu-2.0.14.pom
       - https://maven.fabricmc.net/com/terraformersmc/modmenu/2.0.14/modmenu-2.0.14.pom
       - https://libraries.minecraft.net/com/terraformersmc/modmenu/2.0.14/modmenu-2.0.14.pom
       - file:/C:/Users/thijm/.gradle/caches/fabric-loom/2.0.14/modmenu.jar
       - file:/C:/Users/thijm/Desktop/test 1171/nieuw3/MCPatcherPatcher-main/.gradle/loom-cache/2.0.14/modmenu.jar
       - https://server.bbkr.space/artifactory/libs-snapshot/com/terraformersmc/modmenu/2.0.14/modmenu-2.0.14.pom
     Required by:
         project :fabric
```

I think the mod needs this pom file [https://maven.terraformersmc.com/releases/com/terraformersmc/modmenu/2.0.14], but I don't know how to tell it where to find this file. I would really appriciate all help, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add the maven repository to the `repositories` section of your `build.gradle` file:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://maven.terraformersmc.com/releases"
    }
}
```